# string tokenizer in c until tab and newline

Tags: c, string, token

I have some problem when I want to tokenize the text below and to save tokens in a struct.

```
Wojciech Szczęsny   POL     G   1.95    84  18-04-90    Warsaw  Legia Warszawa
Bacary Sagna    FRA     D   1.76    72  14-02-83    Sens    Auxerre
Per Mertesacker     GER     D   1.98    90  29-09-84    Hannover    Werder Bremen
```

Bewtween words is one space and one tab, and I would like to give the following:

```
t[1].nev = Wojciech Szczesny
 t[1].orsz = POL
 t[1].poz = G
 t[1].mag = 1.95
 t[1].suly = 84
 t[1].datum = 18-04-90
 t[1].varos = Warsaw
 t[1].ecs = Legia Warszawa and etc.
```

I did not edit the txt file because it contains more than 20,000 data.

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct{
    char nev[50];
    char orsz[3];
    char poz[3];
    float mag;
    int suly;
    char datum[10];
    char varos[30];
    char ecs[50];
}JATEKOS;

int main(){
    FILE*f=fopen("Text.txt","rt");
    int i;
    JATEKOS*t;
    t = (JATEKOS*)malloc(3*sizeof(JATEKOS));
    for(i=1;i<=2;++i){
        fscanf(f,"%[^\t]",t[i].nev);
        fscanf(f,"%[^\t]",t[i].orsz);
        fscanf(f,"%[^\n]",t[i].poz);
        fscanf(f,"%[^\t]",&t[i].mag);
        fscanf(f,"%[^\t]",&t[i].suly);
        fscanf(f,"%[^\t]",t[i].datum);
        fscanf(f,"%[^\t]",t[i].varos);
        fscanf(f,"%[^\n]",t[i].ecs);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    for(int i=1;i<=2;++i){
        //printf("%s  %s  %s  %f  %i  %s  %s  %s",t[i].nev,t[i].orsz,t[i].poz,t[i].mag,t[i].suly,t[i].datum,t[i].varos,t[i].ecs);
        printf("%s  %s  %s",t[i].nev,t[i].orsz,t[i].poz);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pull the whole line in with `getline` and then tokenize it with `strtok`?

Comment: Does this compile without warnings? You should **really** test the outcome of relevant system call as there are `fopen()`, `malloc()` and `fscanf()`. Those provide very helpful information, escpecially in cases like this one, when something does not work as expected. It's free info and help so to say!

Comment: I'm missing the question here.  Are you asking for a better solution (in which case be more specific about what you don't like about this one) or are you chasing some bug (in which case be more specific about the problem you are having).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most times C programmers save little utilities for future use - one is whacking up a string using strtok.  Try this it is more flexible:

```
typedef struct{
    char nev[50];
    char orsz[3];
    char poz[3];
    float mag;
    int suly;
    char datum[10];
    char varos[30];
    char ecs[50];
}JATEKOS;
#define MAX_SPLIT 24

char **split(char **result, char *working, const char *delim)
{
     int i;
     char *p=strtok(working, delim);
     for(i=0; p!=NULL && i<MAX_SPLIT; p=strtok(NULL, delim), i++)
     {
         result[i]=p;
         result[i+1]=NULL;
     }
     return result;
}


int main()
{
    FILE*f=fopen("Text.txt","rt");
    int i=0;
    JATEKOS *t, *rec;
    char tmp[128]={0x0};
    char *r[MAX_SPLIT + 1]={NULL};

    t = (JATEKOS*)malloc(3*sizeof(JATEKOS));
    rec=t;
    while(fgets(tmp, 128, f)!=NULL)
    {
        split(r, tmp, "\t \n");
        sprintf(rec->nev, "%s %s", r[0], r[1]);
        strcpy(rec->orsz,   r[2]);
        strcpy(rec->poz ,   r[3]);
        rec->mag=atof(      r[4]);
        rec->suly=atoi(     r[5]);
        strcpy(rec->datum, r[6]);
        strcpy(rec->varos, r[7]);
        strcpy(rec->ecs  , r[8]);
        i++;
        if(i==2) break;
        rec++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    for(i=1;i<=2;++i){
        //printf("%s  %s  %s  %f  %i  %s  %s  %s",t[i].nev,t[i].orsz,t[i].poz,t[i].mag,t[i].suly,t[i].datum,t[i].varos,t[i].ecs);
        printf("%s  %s  %s",t[i].nev,t[i].orsz,t[i].poz);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```